# How to get the maximum value from local database in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce, iqueryable, isolatedstorage

I need to get the maximum value from table that should belongs to particular category.
My code as follows :

```
 private int getHighScores(int _playMode)
    {
        int maxScore = 0;
        using (HangmanScoreDataContext hangmanDB = new HangmanScoreDataContext(@"isostore:/HangmanScoreDB.sdf"))
        {
            IQueryable<TbleHangmanScore> sqlQuery = hangmanDB._tbleHangman;
            sqlQuery = sqlQuery.Where(p => p.playMode == _playMode);                 
            maxScore = sqlQuery.AsQueryable().Max(p => p.score);

        }
        return maxScore;
    }
```

I am getting error like

> an unhandled exception of type 'system.stackoverflowexception' occurred in unknown module.
>   Except maximum  value rest of the things working properly . How can i solve this issue ?

Edit : Problem arises only when the table contains zero numbers of records. Same problem when i trying to get the minimum value also.